# Can't find a function defined myself in the setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a timer function, but I can't call a function inside `setInterval` with a error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function(index):24 CountTime(index):34 (anonymous function)`.

```
$(function() {
    function CountTime(startTime){   
       stopTime = Date.new();
       PassedTime = stopTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime();
       $('#timer').text(PassedTime.toLocaleTimeString());   
    }

    startTime = new Date();
    $('#start').click(function() {
        setInterval(function() { 
            CountTime(startTime);
        }, 1000);
    }); 
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

I put the code in the jsfiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/w2xjz2ze/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
stopTime = Date.new();
```

`Date.new` **is** `undefined`.

You probably wanted

```
stopTime = new Date;
```

But instead of using `new Date` then `getTime`, you can directly use `Date.now()`.

Comment: ... and `PassedTime.toLocaleTimeString()` makes no sense too.

Comment: Thanks! I updated the code `http://jsfiddle.net/w2xjz2ze/1/`. with `toLocalTimeString()` I wanted to make the `Date` instance to `String` like `00:00:30`.

Comment: I got it, `Date.now()` returns millisecond of the whole time from `1970`.